# Python put a triangle inside another one

Tags: python

I’m trying to print a triangle inside of another one so I have the code

```
w = int(input(“Input width of first triangle: “)
c1 = input(“Pick a character: “)
c2 = input(“Pick another character: “)

print(“One: “)
for i in range(“width, 0, -2):
    print(‘{:^{str_len}}’.format(c1 * i, str_len = w * 2))
```

If c1 was * and w was 5 it would print:

```
*****
 ***
  *
```

And now I want it to be like so if c2 was + it would also print:

```
     +
    +++
   +++++
  +*****+
 +++***+++
+++++*+++++
```

Like a triangle with the first one inside it but I don’t know how that would work

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47265894/1639625

Comment: this would be a nice challenge for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
h = 10
h2 = 5
assert(2*h >= h2)

for i in range(h):
    if i >= h2 and i <= 2*h2: #start printing second triangle as well
        s ='%s%s%s' % ('+'*(i-h2),  '*'*(2*h2 - i ), '+'*(i-h2))
        s = " ".join(s)
        print('%s%s' % (' ' * (h - i), s))
    else:
        s = " ".join('+'*i)
        print('%s%s' % (' '*(h-i),s))
```

yields:

```
         +
        + +
       + + +
      + + + +
     * * * * *
    + * * * * +
   + + * * * + +
  + + + * * + + +
 + + + + * + + + +
```